# Integrating react-native to an existing android app?

Tags: android, react-native

I have been trying out React-Native for a while . It would be really helpful if I could build parts of my app using react-native.

Comment: What is the actual question here? Can you elaborate on steps you've taken?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use react-native in your existing android-app. Read through the "Extensibility" section of [this](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/index.html) page, it explains (quite clearly) how it can be done.